# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 10, 250, 250)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am getting error for this code. My original input_shape is (10,250,250,1) . I used tensorflow.keras for Sequential.
My model code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed, Conv2D, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, LSTM, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
model_cnlst = Sequential()
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1,1),activation='relu'),input_shape=(10, 250, 250, 1)))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1,1),activation='relu')))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2,2)))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1,1),activation='relu')))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1,1),activation='relu')))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2,2)))
model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))


model_cnlst.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model_cnlst.add(Dropout(0.2))

model_cnlst.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=False,dropout=0.2)) # used 32 units

model_cnlst.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model_cnlst.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model_cnlst.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_cnlst.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_cnlst.summary()
```

Then for this below code I get this error:

```
 
 
 
 
 
 
 history_new_cnlst=model_cnlst.fit(train_dataset_new,train_labels,epochs=20,batch_size=10,validation_data=(validation_dataset_new,validation_labels),
callbacks=callbacks_list_cnlst)
```

The error Message is:

```
Epoch 1/20
....
----> 3                callbacks=callbacks_list_cnlst)

........

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 10, 250, 250)
```

My `callbacks_list_cnlst` is defined as:

```
callbacks_list_cnlst=[tensorflow.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
monitor='acc',patience=3),
               tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
               filepath='cnn_lstm_model_new3.h5',
               monitor='val_loss',
               save_best_only=True),
                tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = "val_loss", factor = 0.1, patience = 3)
               ]
```

Comment: Please add your model's code as this seems related to input shape that you've passed to model.

Comment: I added the model's code. Please check @Frightera

Comment: Remove `TimeDistributed` layer, It just a wrapper, It tries to move along axis=1, and apply 2D Convolution for each index, ignoring batch size, your input is just a 3d, it similar try to apply 2D Convolution on 2D Input.

Comment: @4.Pi.n If I remove TimeDistribution from Max Pooling, it gets error. I removed TimeDistribution from Conv2D and BatchNormalization. But I let TImeDistribution to stay in MaxPooling. Then I get error in this line: `model_cnlst.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences=False,dropout=0.2)) # used 32 units`
It says: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1113920)`

Comment: `TimeDistributed`, is not required at all given your input shape, what's error you have got by removing it.

Comment: What your inputs represents, images ?

Comment: yes 250*250 greyscaled images @4.Pi.n

Comment: So `input_shape=(10, 250, 250, 1)`, is wrong. `input_shape=(250, 250, 1)`, and remove all TimeDistributed layers. Additionally  `LSTM` layer, means nothing here just adds more overhead to your computer.

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed` layer expects input tensor of shape (batch, time, ...)` something like example The batch input shape is `(32, 10, 128, 128, 3)`, Consider a batch of 32 video samples, where each sample is a 128x128 RGB image with channels_last data format, across 10 timesteps.  For more details refer the [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed). Thanks!